# Type The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library android-support-v7-appcompat/bin/android-support-v7-appcompat.jar

Tags: android, android-actionbar-compat

I just got some kind of error when trying to using Action Bar Compat support library to my project, I don't know what's wrong, because I have followed the instructions from this link > http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

So, this is the screen shot of the error .. 
[image: IDE]

Comment: It seems to me Eclipse can't find the lib on this folder, try to add the jar again. Or you can just copy the lib to your libs folder and then click with the right button and add to build path

Comment: the jar file was exist in the lib folder of appcompat project.

Comment: In your screenshot the imported lib is pointed to be on the bin folder, try to remove the lib and add it again fallowing the above instruction

Answer (score 30):

I also encountered such problem. My error was:
The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library 'C:\development\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702\workspace\appcompat_v7\bin\appcompat_v7.jar'

To solve this, I went project>properties>java build path>libraries>add jars>appcompat_v7>libs>, then I selected android-support-v7-appcompat.jar. After this, I went to project>clean. This fixed the problem. Hope you find my hint helpful.

Comment: Without fail I find myself returning here, thank you

Answer (score 7):

As in the [instructions](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html) you mentioned, please make sure to follow this step to add .jar files instead of directly go to Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries to add them.

> In the new library project, expand the libs/ folder, right-click each
>   .jar file and select Build Path > Add to Build Path. For example, when
>   creating the the v7 appcompat project, add both the
>   android-support-v4.jar and android-support-v7-appcompat.jar files to
>   the build path.

Answer (score 5):

I just had this issue, when creating a new project.  After following the instructions from the link you provided, close your project, then close Eclipse, restart Eclipse, open your project then clean and build your project.  This did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

These days I used the latest android support library 21 and got the same issue.
I followed the answer of @dazilli,but do not work.
Just now,I updated the JDK from 6 to 7,then it solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

First of all cleanup a library project and build project check library project has bin files after that clean your project its work for me

Answer (score 1):

- andriod platform must be android 5.0 and set 'target=21'
- make sure download Extras[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case the files were in appcombat_v7/lib folder, so what i did is right-click the .jar files (there will be two files select android-support-v4.jar) and then select Build Path>Add to Build Path. What it does is that it adds this file to the Build Path (i.e it will add this file to the "bin folder") which will solve the problem.