# Build Path 'Android Dependecies'

Tags: android, eclipse, jquery-mobile

I'm a beginner in android, when I create a new project I got those 2 errors always and I don't know why.

```
1/  The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library  'C:\Users\POSTE5\workspace\appcompat_v7\bin\appcompat_v7.jar' Testapp Build Path Problem

2/  error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.  styles_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line 75 Android AAPT Problem
```

Comment: Did you do any research to address the issue?

Comment: of course i did but nothing

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the error `The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library  'C:\Users\POSTE5\workspace\appcompat_v7\bin\appcompat_v7.jar'  Testapp Build Path Problem` error, you can check this quoted **dazilli's** answer given here: 
[Type The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library android-support-v7-appcompat/bin/android-support-v7-appcompat.jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21678510/type-the-container-android-dependencies-references-non-existing-library-androi)

> I also encountered such problem. My error was: The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library
>   'C:\development\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702\workspace\appcompat_v7\bin\appcompat_v7.jar'
>
> To solve this, I went project>properties>java build path>libraries>add jars>appcompat_v7>libs>, then I selected
>   android-support-v7-appcompat.jar. After this, I went to project>clean.
>   This fixed the problem. Hope you find my hint helpful.

Hope this helps.

Comment: If the question is answered elsewhere, you should just link to it in the comments, and maybe leave a flag for moderators to mark as duplicate instead of reproducing the answer here. see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled

Comment: i did the same as you did but nothing change